# Is there a way of assigning subscripts/superscripts as shown below?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I've been working on a VBA macro which generates a PPT presentation based on certain values from a spreadsheet. The macro calls a PPT template which I created, and essentially pastes the specified values on placeholders I inputted in the template presentation.

My issue comes with the following lines of code whereby I'm creating a text which should read:

Flow_coolant = (imported cell value) dPCoolant2 + (imported cell value) dPCoolant + (imported cell value)

where "Coolant" are subscripts and "2" is a superscript so as to denote a power.

```
    Set PPSlide9 = myPresentation.Slides(9)
    With PPSlide9.Shapes("Text Placeholder 1").TextFrame
        With .TextRange.Lines(4)
                .Text = "FlowCoolant = " & Range("DT_Motor_a") & " dPCoolant2 + " & Range("DT_Motor_b") & " dPCoolant + " & Range("DT_Motor_c") & " [L/min]"
                .Characters(5, 7).Font.Subscript = msoTrue
                .Characters(25, 7).Font.Subscript = msoTrue
                .Characters(32, 1).Font.Superscript = msoTrue
                .Characters(46, 7).Font.Subscript = msoTrue
        End With
    End With
```

As seen in the code, I'm specifying a certain character order number to be made into a subscript and superscript. However, this does not work well when the imported cell value returns a negative value, or an integer as the subscript and superscripts would then be assigned to the incorrect characters because the total character number in the string changes.

Is there a way of specifying the text "Coolant" to be a subscript rather than specifying character number 5-12 subscripted as I've done on: .Characters(5, 7).Font.Subscript = msoTrue

Thanks!

Comment: Search for the string "coolant" this will give you the starting position and, thus the first character to be a subscript

Answer (score 0):

Here's a token-replacement approach:

```
Sub MainSub()

    Dim pptApp As Object, shp As Object, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set pptApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application") 'reference running PPT
    
    Set shp = pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1) 'shape to be modified
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    
    'replace tokens in the referenced shape
    replaceToken shp, "<v1>", ws.Range("A1").Value
    replaceToken shp, "<v2>", ws.Range("A2").Value
    replaceToken shp, "<v3>", ws.Range("A3").Value

End Sub

Sub replaceToken(shp As Object, token As String, v)
    Dim p As Long
    With shp.TextFrame2.TextRange
        p = InStr(1, .Text, token, vbTextCompare)
        If p > 0 Then
            .Characters(p, Len(token)).Text = v
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Before and after:

[image]

Adjusting your posted code:

```
Dim shp as Object
'...
Set PPSlide9 = myPresentation.Slides(9)
Set shp = PPSlide9.Shapes("Text Placeholder 1")

replaceToken shp, "<v1>", Range("DT_Motor_a").Value
replaceToken shp, "<v1>", Range("DT_Motor_b").Value
replaceToken shp, "<v1>", Range("DT_Motor_c").Value
'...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the suggestion, really appreciate it!

I'm very new to VBA macro so apologies if I'm making this harder than it seems. My original code is placed within a Sub, and when it comes to trying to input your suggested modification within it, I'm required to end the "master" Sub before inputting the Sub procedures from your suggestion. I'm struggling to get around defining replaceToken in another way aside from using Sub or Function which will require me to end my "master" Sub. Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: I've updated my code so it will run from Excel - it should give you some idea of how to implement the change in your existing code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim! Had to make some tweaks to it, but this works wonders